# How to submit input text value if we show all input text with help of map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to accept all input when user clicks on submit button.

I have dynamic data as follows:

```
 {
        "x": [
            {
                "datatypename": "string",
                "default": "",
                "name": "a"
            },
            {
                "datatypename": "string",
                "default": "aa",
                "name": "b"
            }
        ],
        "y": [
            {
                "datatypename": "string",
                "default": "",
                "name": "a"
            }
        ],
        "z": [
            {
                "datatypename": "string",
                "default": "aa",
                "name": "a"
            },
            {
                "datatypename": "string",
                "default": "bb",
                "name": "b"
            },
        ]
 }
```

I am creating form for above data using below code.

```
deploymodel = (frominput_values: any) => {
  console.log("Frominput Values : ",frominput_values)
};
constructor(props: ToscaDeploymentPageProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    frominput_values: '',
    }
}
render() {
const handleDefaultChange = (frominput_values: any) => {
      this.setState({
         frominput_values: frominput_values
      })
}
return (
<>
<Form>
{ this.state.inputsdata ? 
    Object.keys(this.state.inputsdata).map((valuesmodel, _I) => (
    <FormFieldGroupExpandable
      required
      toggleAriaLabel={valuesmodel}
      header={
        <FormFieldGroupHeader
          titleText={{ text: valuesmodel + ' Inputs', id: valuesmodel }}
        />
      }
    >
    { this.state.inputsdata ?
      this.state.inputsdata[valuesmodel].map((valuesmodel1, _idx) => (                               
      <>
        <FormGroup isRequired label={valuesmodel1.name} fieldId={valuesmodel1.name}>
          {valuesmodel1.default ?
            <TextInput
             isRequired
             type="text"
             placeholder={valuesmodel1.default}
             id={valuesmodel1.name}
             name={valuesmodel1.name}
             value={valuesmodel1.default}
             onChange={handleDefaultChange}
             /> : 
             <TextInput
               isRequired
               type="text"
               placeholder={valuesmodel1.default}
               id={valuesmodel1.name}
               name={valuesmodel1.name}
               value={frominput_values}
               onChange={handleDefaultChange}
             />
           }
        </FormGroup>
        </>
      )) :"Loading..."
    } 
    </FormFieldGroupExpandable>
  )):"Loading..."
}
<ActionGroup>
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={ () => 
   {this.deploymodel(this.state.frominput_values)}}>Submit</Button>
</ActionGroup>
</Form>
</>
}
}
```

In onChange function, I set the user value to state and use it while clicking on submit button.
Now I want to accept all values on click of submit which are entered by a user in the form.

How to do that any idea?